# NPM/Cordova permissions Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir

Tags: linux, macos, cordova, npm, file-permissions

When I run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation` I receive the following error. I have tried enable 777 on this folder, setting myself as the owner etc. In these circumstances I'm not allowed to use `sudo`, but am confident if I could that would solve the problem.

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-geolocation': Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/build/device/libCordova.a'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:952:18)
    at GlobSync._readdir (/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/glob/sync.js:275:41)
    at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/glob/sync.js:254:20)
    at GlobSync._readdir (/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/glob/sync.js:263:17)
    at GlobSync._processReaddir (/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/glob/sync.js:135:22)
    at GlobSync._process (/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/glob/sync.js:360:10)
    at GlobSync._process (/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/glob/sync.js:128:10)
    at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/glob/sync.js:363:10)
Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Users/username/documents/core/myapp/app/platforms/ios/build/device/libCordova.a'
```

Comment: first you gotta tell us the version of cordova and plugin you are using. Also is it happening only for this particular plugin addition or for all?

Comment: @Gandhi I fixed it. All I had to do was reinstall cordova without using sudo

Comment: @Gandhi I did mention it was a permissions error which generally speaking would rule out the version of Cordova or the specific plugin being relevant

Comment: since you have mentioned geolocation plugin specifically, i thought it could be plugin specific

Comment: @Ghandi Fair point though I only meant that as example but should have made clearer. Will delete question once bounty expires. Thanks anyway

Comment: thanks for the info.. cheers. Thought it could be access related but for a bounty question guess it wont be that straight forward solution though

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[NPM issue's](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/194)

You can fix this problem using one of three options:

```
  1).Change the permission to npm's default directory.
  2).Change npm's default directory to another directory.
  3).Install node with a package manager that takes care of this for you.
```

You should back-up your computer before moving forward.

Option 1: Change the permission to npm's default directory

1).Find the path to npm's directory:

```
    npm config get prefix
```

For many systems, this will be /usr/local.

WARNING: If the displayed path is just /usr, switch to Option 2 or you will mess up your permissions.

2).Change the owner of npm's directories to the name of the current user (your username!):

```
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

This changes the permissions of the sub-folders used by npm and some other tools (lib/node_modules, bin, and share).

Option 2: Change npm's default directory to another directory

There are times when you do not want to change ownership of the default directory that npm uses (i.e. /usr) as this could cause some problems, for example if you are sharing the system with other users.

Instead, you can configure npm to use a different directory altogether. In our case, this will be a hidden directory in our home folder.

1).Make a directory for global installations:

```
 mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

2).Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

3).Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

4).Back on the command line, update your system variables:

```
 source ~/.profile
```

Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.

```
 npm install -g jshint
```

nstead of steps 2-4 you can also use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify ~/.profile):

```
  NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```

Option 3: Use a package manager that takes care of this for you.

If you're doing a fresh install of node on Mac OS you can avoid this problem altogether by using the Homebrew package manager. Homebrew sets things up out of the box with the correct permission.

```
  brew install node
```

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer however I fixed this by simply uninstalling cordova and then reinstalling it without using `sudo`

Comment: That's very nice i heard from you we want solution that's it.. go ahead

Answer (score 1):

For **Mac** users, if you are looking for a quick answer, you can edit the permissions of the `.npm` folder located at `/Users/$(whoami)/.npm`.

1. Go to `.npm` parent folder (to prevent running the 2nd command in the wrong place).

```
$ cd /Users/$(whoami)
```

2. Run chmod to change the permissions of the `.npm` folder.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 .npm/*
```

That's how I solved on my case.

Comment: Thank you. I was having similar EACCES errors with my Cordova app in the OSX terminal and using a variation of this resolved those issues for me: `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/MyUsername/Documents/Projects/MyApp/*`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else arrives with a Mac cordova environment that has sudo'd itself beyond repair, this was my only solution (after a lot of pain):

- backup everything
- remove all cordova platforms (WARNING: this will wreck anything custom you've done within a platform, thus the backup)
- uninstall cordova globally
- uninstall npm; I just used the basic command from their site: sudo npm uninstall npm -g
- install NVM
- through that, install Node long-term-stable
- install cordova (no more sudo required)
- take permissions of your project directory (I did my whole user directory recursively)
- add your platforms
- diff back in any of your customizations
- find a comfortable chair and drink scotch